# How to do a trigger event only for the first element in the Menu

Tags: jquery

On page load up , i need to do a trigger call on the menu

I need to do it only for the first element that is Bottle in  my case

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper" id="swipecontainer">
    <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-visible swiper-slide-active"><span>Bottle</span>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-visible"><span>Cool Drinks</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my code

```
$(document).on("click", ".swiper-slide", function (event) {
    alert('Clciked');
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
$(".swiper-slide").trigger("click");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7d060586/1/

The problem i am facing is that it is doing a trigger call for all the items present in the menu

Could you please let me know how to d it only  for the first item of the Menu .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either use [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) or [`.eq(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$("#swipecontainer .swiper-slide:first").trigger("click");
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wdyk84c4/)

---

```
$("#swipecontainer .swiper-slide").first().trigger("click");
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/uqkpyct2/)

---

```
$("#swipecontainer .swiper-slide").eq(0).trigger("click");
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/37suab1a/)

Answer (score 0):

Using a css selector would be the easiest way IMO.

```
//cache element
var element = $('.swiper-slide:first')
element.on("click", function (event) {
    alert('Clicked');
});
```